Is there any way to use Cypress for unit testing functions? (React Framework)
I am trying to test helper functions of my application using cypress, but I am not sure if it is possible, or how I could make it work. I know cypress it meant to be used for e2e and component testing, but it seems like there could be a way to make it work for functions too. I'm trying to move away from Jest because Jest is incompatible with react 18. There is also a memory leak issue between node and jest which it seems I can't fix because create-react-app does not allow us to use the configuration settings to patch the leak.
For example if I have a file called helpers.js (I've simplified the functions for readability)
export const sum = (a, b) => a+b
export const subtract = (a, b) => a-b

I want to be able to import and test these functions in cypress. I thought it might look something like:
import * as helpers from 'helpers.js';

context('Helpers', () => {
    describe('sum', () => {
    it('should add the values correctly', () => {
        const result = helpers.sum(1, 2);
        expect(result).to.equal(3);
    });
    });
});


I have also tried creating cypress commands and using those in the tests
import { sum } from 'helpers.js'
Cypress.Commands.add('sum', (a, b) => sum(a, b))

context('Helpers', () => {
    describe('sum', () => {
    it('should add the values correctly', () => {
        const result = cy.sum(1, 2);
        expect(result).to.equal(3);
    });
    });
});


However both scenarios result in an error of Cannot access 'subtract' before initialization. If anyone has any insight, it would be greatly appreciated!

Use vitest instead of jest then, not cypress for this

When you specify an import as an absolute path import * as helpers from 'helpers.js', it assumes it's a package in node_modules.
To specify a local file, add a relative path on the import
import * as helpers from './helpers.js'

it('should add the values correctly', () => {
  const result = helpers.sum(1, 2)
  expect(result).to.equal(3)
})

This now passes when you run it.
